# Selection Sort pattern

Tags: loops, sorting, design-patterns, for-loop, selection

I've been given the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int ordsel[4][4]={ {3,10,12,7},
                   {33,22,13,21},
                   {15,6,3,30},
                   {16,20,27,2}};
void imprimir()
{
    for (int k=0;k<4;k++)
    {
        for (int m=0;m<4;m++)
          printf("%d\t",ordsel[k][m]);
      printf("\n");
    }    
}

void ordenar()
{
    int cmenor, aux, ia, fmenor;

    for (int k = 0 ; k < 4 ; k++)
    {
        for (int m = 0 ; m < 4 ; m++)
        {
            fmenor=k;
            cmenor=m;
            ia=m;

            for (int i=k;i<4;i++)
            {
                for (int j=ia;j<4;j++)
                {
                   if (ordsel[i][j]<ordsel[fmenor][cmenor])
                   {
                        cmenor=j;
                        fmenor=i;
                   }
                } 

                ia = 0;
            }
         } 

         aux = ordsel[k][m];
         ordsel[k][m] = ordsel[fmenor][cmenor];
         ordsel[fmenor][cmenor] = aux;
      }
}

// Pregunta 3 Parcial III 1415-1
main()
{
printf("Programa que Ordenada una Matriz 4 x 4 por el Metodo Selectivo\n");
printf("\n");
printf("\n       MATRIZ INICIAL\n");
imprimir();
printf("\n");
ordenar(); 
printf("      MATRIZ ORDENADA\n");
imprimir();
printf("\n");
system("pause");
}
```

[SelectionSort](https://gist.github.com/Crawlingvx/bf7412c8da36eda657d8)

I'm struggling to find any kind of pattern on how is this sorting method supposed to work. If anyone could explain, I'd appreciate it. Also, is there any way of doing it with only 2 "for" loops? I think the major problem is that I can't wrap my head around the 3 "for" loops to navigate a Matrix. Thank you.

Comment: Can nobody help me with this?

Comment: You might want to consider changing your question title to "Understanding Selection Sort on a 2D array". That is probably a more accurate description of your question and hence might invite more replies.

Comment: Post the code here, instead of a link.

Answer (score 1):

The typical Selection Sort works on 1 dimensional (i.e., 1D) array. The code you posted simply uses the same sorting principle to sort a 2D array (i.e., a matrix).

I will first explain how Selection Sort works on 1D array, and then extend it to explain how your code works on a 2D array.

## Selection Sort

Selection Sort works by looping over each element in an N element array A. At iteration i, where 0 <= i < N, it finds the smallest element
between A[i] and A[N-1] (i.e., from index i onwards), and swap that element into A[i].

When i = 0, the algorithm swaps the smallest element into A[0], when i = 1, it swaps the second smallest element into A[1] (since the smallest is already in A[0] and it is searching from A[1] to A[N-1]). Performing this operation for i = 0 to N-1 sorts A.

```
void selection_sort(int A[], int N)
{
    // Loop over each element.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // At each iteration, put the next smallest element
        // into the correct position.

        // Find the smallest element from A[i] onwards
        int min_element_index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[min_element_index])
                min_element_index = j;
        }

        // Swap the smallest element between A[i] and A[N-1] into A[i]
        int tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[min_element_index];
        A[min_element_index] = tmp;
    }
}
```

You can see a visualization of how this algorithm works [here](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/visualization/sorting.html).

## Selection Sort (2D case)

You code basically does the following:

1) Loop over each element ordsel[k][m] in the matrix:

```
  for (int k=0;k<4;k++)
        for (int m=0;m<4;m++)
        {
```

This corresponds to the outer-most loop in the 1D case (above).

2) Within the above nested loops, considering element ordsel[k][m], it finds the smallest element from ordsel[k][m] onwards:

```
    fmenor=k;  // Row index of the smallest element
    cmenor=m;  // Col index of the smallest element
    ia=m;      // Starting position of the col index
    for (int i=k;i<4;i++)
    {
        for (int j=ia;j<4;j++) // Start at col ia := m.
        {
            if (ordsel[i][j]<ordsel[fmenor][cmenor])
            {
                cmenor=j;
                fmenor=i;
            }
        }

        ia=0;  // Reset col index to first col when we move to next row
```

This corresponds to the inner loop in the 1D case (above).

## Selection Sort (2D) using 2 for loops

The trick here is to view the 4 x 4 2D array as a 1D array of 16 elements. This reduces the problem to the 1D sorting case above. But to make things work, we must be able to compute the row and col indices in this 2D array using the indices looping over the "1D" view of the array.

The 2D array `ordsel` can be viewed as:

```
int A[] = {3, 10, 12, 7, 33, 22, 13, 21, 15, 6, 3, 30, 16, 20, 27, 2}
```

Now `A[0] == ordsel[0][0]`, `A[1] == ordsel[0][1]`, ...

In particular, `A[5] == ordsel[1][0]`, `A[6] == ordsel[1][2]`, `A[7] == ordsel[1][3]`, ..., `A[15] == ordsel[3][3]`.

Notice you can compute the row and col indices of `ordsel[k][m]` from index of `A[j]` like so:

```
int k = j / NUM_COLS;  // Row index
int m = j % NUM_COLS;  // Col index
```

where we made use of integer truncation to round down `j` and the modulus operator `%` to compute the column index.

```
int NUM_ROWS = 4;
int NUM_COLS = 4;
void selection_sort_2D()
{
    // Loop over 2D array as a 1D array
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS; i++)
    {
        // The trick is to compute the row and col indices
        // from the index i.
        int cur_row = i / NUM_COLS;  // Index of current row
        int cur_col = i % NUM_COLS;  // and col

        int min_row_idx = cur_row;
        int min_col_idx = cur_col;
        for (int j = i; j < NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS; j++)
        {
            // Similar to how we compute cur_row, cur_col
            int k = j / NUM_COLS;  // Row index
            int m = j % NUM_COLS;  // Col index
            if (ordsel[k][m] < ordsel[min_row_idx][min_col_idx])
            {
                min_row_idx = k;
                min_col_idx = m;
            }
        }

        // Swap
        int tmp = ordsel[cur_row][cur_col];
        ordsel[cur_row][cur_col] = ordsel[min_row_idx][min_col_idx];
        ordsel[min_row_idx][min_col_idx] = tmp;
    }
}
```